# Relief algorithm in R

Tags: r

I'm using CORElearn package to execute attrEval formula to obtain a variable rank using the Relief algorithm:

```
library("CORElearn")
result <- attrEval(ncol(data), data, estimator="RReliefFequalK", ReliefIterations=100)
```

My problem is that the result is output in a "numerical" class:

```
V1            V2            V3            V4            V5 
-0.0178230599 -0.0497431971  0.0687728157  0.1098432491  0.1247375758
```

And I don't know how to convert it into a vector.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: That just looks like a named vector. What do you need to do with that result that you cannot?

Comment: When I select an element like result[1] I obtain name and number instead of only the number

Comment: Named vectors should perform just like any other vector. If you really need to unname if for some reason, use `unname()`.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is but you can use `names()` to get the names of the features and `as.numeric()` to get the values